# SQL, MS access VBA update

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I would like to seek help in my update statement in ms access. I don't know if possible but can we incorporate SELECT statement in UPDATE statement?

Here's the code that I have problem.

```
  DoCmd.RunSQL _
        "UPDATE tab_lists " & _
        "SET " & _
        "total_calls                = ((SELECT COUNT(filler3) FROM table WHERE [attempt_counter] = 5)  " & _
        "WHERE " & _
        "listid                     = " & listid1 & ""
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.

I prefer CurrentDb.Execute:

`CurrentDb.Execute ("UPDATE tab_lists SET total_calls = (SELECT COUNT(filler3) AS CountFill FROM table WHERE [attempt_counter] = 5) WHERE listid = " & listid1)`

However, saving aggregate data is usually a bad idea. Should just calculate when needed.

Your table is named table? That is also not good.

Comment: What is the difference using the DoCmd.RunSQL over CurrentDB.Execute? My table name is actually tab_counter, thanks for your advise.

Comment: CurrentDb.Execute won't trigger warnings.